# Required Field Validator not working for Databound dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, visual-studio-2012, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a drop down list with required field validator that is not showing up when the user clicks on the button. The user has to select an item from the drop down list, if he leaves it at --Select One-- the required field validator will fire. I noticed that on firebug it shows visibility as hidden.

```
<span id="MainContent_RequiredFieldValidator1" style="color: red; visibility: hidden;">*</span>
```

This works for my other dropdownlists that are not Databound. It shows visibility:visible for this dropdownlists.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCenter" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"         
    CssClass="form-control textBoxAsp" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCenter" 
    DataTextField="Desc" DataValueField="CenterID">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="0" Selected="True" />
 </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
     ControlToValidate="ddlCenter"
     Text="*"
     ForeColor="Red"
     ErrorMessage="Center is required."
     InitialValue ="--Select One--"
     ValidationGroup="InsertCenter" />

  <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ValidationGroup="InsertCenter" />

   <a runat="server" onserverclick="btnAddCenter_Click" id="btnAddUser" validationgroup="InsertEmployee">Add Center</a>
```

I tried setting `Display="Static"`,but the Validator control's style property is actually set as "`visibility:hidden`".

I tried setting set `Display="Dynamic"` , but the Validator controls style property is actually set as "`display:none`"

Any ideas?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken--and I might be, I just woke up--`Select One` is still an option. So it isn't a matter of the required field validator failing, it's just that it doesn't know what "required" means. You might have to write a custom JavaScript validator.

Comment: Does adding `ValidationGroup="InsertCenter"` to the DropDownList fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Initial Value` refers to the `Value` property of the `DropDownList` rather than the `Text` value; hence try setting the `Initial Value` of the `RequiredFieldValidator` to 0.

Comment: ahhh. That was it, I overlooked that. Thank you